# How to make absolute positioned pop-up bar "push down" other content?

Tags: css

Say I have a page with a fixed position navbar on top. When the user loses connection to the app, I want a red warning bar to pop up above the navbar. I use position absolute and top: 0 to achieve this. How can I then push down the navbar so that it isn't hidden behind the warning bar?

Codepen to demonstrate: https://codepen.io/meek/pen/RjKxbz

HTML

```
<div class="nav">menu</div>
<div class="warning">warning</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.warning {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You would have to animate it to move it's top position at the same speed as the warning bar comes in, the easiest way though would be to prepend the warning bar to the nav bar and make it relative and change the height to a min-height.  Can you show the code that makes the warning appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the warning inside the nav. That way the content inside of the nav will be pushed down when the warning shows up. Put the background color and other details on a div that's inside of the nav. Put the warning div right above that.